# Detecting React children array length in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that can accept React `children` as either a node or an array of nodes. I want to be able to detect if `children` is an array of nodes, but I am getting the following Typescript error:

> TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number | true | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | ... 47 more ... | (ReactNode[] & ReactPortal)'.   Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.

Is there a way in Typescript where I detect if `children` has length? Thanks.

```js
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
}

const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  if (children && children.length) {
    return children.map((child) => (
      <div>{child}</div>
    ));
  }

  return children;
};

export default SampleComponent;
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to avoid React.FC, here's a link to a MR https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) API for dealing with the `props.children` (which is an *opaque data structure*).

Also, `React.Children` has methods like [count](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrencount), [map](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) etc.

```
if (React.Children.count(children)) {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => <div>{ ..todo.. }</div>)
}
```

It has TypeScript support too. So, you won't need to cast the types.

Answer (score 4):

[Update]

Please check out [Ajeet Shah's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66740808) with using React.Children API.

[Original]

Cast children to React.ReactNode[] before checking length like this:

```
(children as React.ReactNode[]).length
```

You could also create a type predicate:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Answer (score 1):

Try `React.Children.count(children)`

Answer (score 0):

### The best way in this case is not use Reacf.FC

Defined the props like `const MyButton = (props: MyProps)=>...`
Or use `React.VFC`

[Function Components - Why is `React.FC` discouraged?](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components)

[image]